# Как изменить данные в выбранном ListViewItem?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, xaml

Когда я делаю Hold event на ListView я получаю свой Item в обрабочик. Сейчас как мне можно изменить какое либо значение в выбранном ListBoxItem?

Репутация не позволяет вставить скрин.

```
async void Add_To_Favorites(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection(dbPath);
            var stop = (e.OriginalSource as FrameworkElement).DataContext as Model.StopsTable;
            connection.Query<Model.StopsTable>("update stops set favorites = 'True' where id = " + stop.id);

            List<Model.StopsTable> StopNames = await Task.Run(() => Load_Stops(parameter));
            RoutesStopNamesList.ItemsSource = StopNames;
           (**1**)
        }
В пункте 1 нужно вместо верхних 2х строчек просто изменить символ в ListViewItem. Так как я не умею то загружаю данные снова и по логике приложения оно изменяет символ само, но при этом скролл прокручивается вверх ListView.
```

Вывожу в таком XAML'e:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Background="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="552" Margin="0,88,0,-20" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="400">
            <ListView x:Name="RoutesStopNamesList" Background="White"  Margin="20,10,20,20" SelectionChanged="SelectStopNameTime">
                <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                    </Style>
                </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel x:Name="MainStackPanel" Background="White" Orientation="Horizontal" Height="70" Holding="Grid_Holding">
                            <SymbolIcon x:Name="SymbolIconChange"  Symbol="{Binding Path=symbol}" Foreground="{Binding Path=color}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,10,0"/>
                            <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=name}" Foreground="Black" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" FontSize="20" Width="290"></TextBlock>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=next_bus}" Foreground="DarkGray" FontSize="14" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Left"></TextBlock>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </Grid>
```

Модель:

```
public class StopsTable
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public int n_id { get; set; }
        public int r_id { get; set; }
        public int s_id { get; set; }
        public int d_id { get; set; }
        public string weekdays { get; set; }
        public string saturday { get; set; }
        public string sunday { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string direction_name { get; set; }
        public string num { get; set; }
        public string favorites { get; set; }
        public string symbol { get; set; }
        public object color { get; set; }
        public string next_bus { get; set; }
    }
```

В итоге при запуске Add_To_Favorites метода происходит добавление определенной остановки в избранное, в этот момент мне нужно просто поменять символ в выбранном item.
Сначала там стоит просто Star символ, а мне надо на SolidStar.

Comment: Что есть тип элементов вашей коллекции, к которой привязан `ListView`? Вы можете получить нужный элемент коллекции, или проблема именно в этом?

Comment: @Erick_Voodoo: 1) flyout наверное не важен для вопроса, правильно?

2) вы можете на этом самом hold получить элемент коллекции, который вас интересует?

3) если да, зачем вам listviewitem? Неужели вы собрались прямо редактировать UI-контрол? Не делайте так ни в коем случае, делайте через `Binding`.

Comment: @Erick_Voodoo: Ну, подумайте немного сами. Код, который вы привели, написан вами? Вы видите, откуда берётся там ваш символ? Из привязки к элементу коллекции. Ну вот и поменяйте привязанное свойство элемента коллекции.

Comment: @Erick_Voodoo: Тут я не понял ничего. Вы говорили в позапрошлом комментарии, что вы **получаете** элемент коллекции, а в прошлом, что не знаете, как к нему добраться.

(У вас лимит комментариев, удаляйте старые.)

Comment: @Erick_Voodoo: Если бы вы дали пример кода и классов (отдельно VM, отдельно View), возможно, было бы легче вам помочь.

Comment: Обновил вопрос, просмотрите его еще раз, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вроде бы ясно. Смотрите, в чём проблема.

С точки зрения дизайна программы, ваша коллекция — не ViewModel-, а Model-элементы. Это не вполне правильно с точки зрения реализации паттерна MVVM, View не должен видеть Model, а только ViewModel.

С технической точки зрения, изменения в свойствах `StopsTable` не видны вашему контролу потому, что `StopsTable` не реализует `INotifyPropertyChanged` (и содержит обыкновенные свойства, а не DependencyProperty), и таким образом контролу просто неоткуда узнать, что у вас там поменялось значение.

Как решать?

1. Если вы пишете программу с MVVM, вам нужно иметь коллекцию VM-объектов.
2. Если вы хотите остаться в рамках текущего дизайна, вам нужно реализовать `INotifyPropertyChanged` в `StopsTable`.

Comment: А у меня точно MVVM паттерн? Потому что я подбивал все под MVC. Есть модель, есть вьюха, есть контроллер с методами

Comment: @Erick_Voodoo: А, понял. Нет, MVVM и MVC — разные вещи. Тогда вам, наверное, придётся делать второй вариант.

Я не соображу сходу, как отдельный контроллер сможет попросить UI обновить Binding. (Это мог бы быть третий, наиболее удобный вариант.)

Comment: Ну ведь через контроллер я заполняю лист, стало быть, можно и как-то изменить его. Видел примеры того, как люди меняют фон в итемах. Но на конкретные элементы не попадалось.

Comment: @Erick_Voodoo: Изменить сам список — не проблема. У вас есть элемент списка, вы его и меняете. Проблема в том, чтобы UI увидел ваши изменения и «самообновился». Это правильный путь. Для этого, например, вполне подойдёт `INotifyPropertyChanged` (вы уже попробовали?).

Comment: Знал бы я, как сделать с помощью этого) Позже попробую, спасибо))

Comment: @Erick_Voodoo: Вы не знаете, как имплементировать `INotifyPropertyChanged`? o_O

Вот вам [пример](http://pastebin.com/gFHns5pb), только никому не говорите.

Comment: Я самоучка) Про многое не знаю) Спасибо большое за помощь)